# Respect last line if it's not terminated with a new line char (\n) when using read

Tags: bash, shell, built-in

I have noticed for a while that `read` never actually reads the last line of a file if there is not, at the end of it, a "newline" character. This is understandable if one consider that, as long as there is not a "newline" character in a file, it is as if it contained 0 line (which is quite difficult to admit !). See, for example, the following:

```
$ echo 'foo' > bar ; wc -l bar
1 bar
```

But...

```
$ echo -n 'bar' > foo ; wc -l foo
0 foo
```

The question is then: how can I handle such situations when using `read` to process files which have not been created or modified by myself, and about which I don't know if they actually end up with a "newline" character ?

Comment: Actually, `read` reads that unterminated last line just fine. The issue is with using its return value in a loop – see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14547230/990363).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`read` does, in fact, read an unterminated line into the assigned var (`$REPLY` by default). It also returns false on such a line, which just means ‘end of file’; directly using its return value in the classic `while` loop thus skips that one last line. If you change the loop logic slightly, you can process non-new line terminated files correctly, without need for prior sanitisation, with `read`:

```
while read -r || [[ -n "$REPLY" ]]; do
    # your processing of $REPLY here
done < "/path/to/file"
```

Note this is much faster than solutions relying on externals.

*Hat tip to [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) for improving the loop logic.*

Comment: Just wondering: How is this differen from `cat file | while read -r`?

Comment: @Pumbaa80 it doesn’t launch an external process, which makes it faster, and the loop doesn’t execute in a subshell, again faster and also [free of unexpected side effects from switching shell contexts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: This doesn't quite work, since if the file does end with newline it'll run the loop an extra time with REPLY set to "". Use `while read -r || [ -n "$REPLY" ]; do` instead.

Comment: Note for context: “this” in the comment by @GordonDavisson was an `until` loop using a Boolean control variable set to `read`’s exit value that would indeed set `$REPLY` to an empty string when the last line of the file was correctly terminated.

Comment: @kopischke: this is definitely the cleaner way of doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

POSIX requires any line in a file have a newline character at the end to denote it is a line. But [this site](http://backreference.org/2010/05/23/sanitizing-files-with-no-trailing-newline/) offers a solution to exactly the scenario you are describing. Final product is this chunklet.

```
newline='
'
lastline=$(tail -n 1 file; echo x); lastline=${lastline%x}
[ "${lastline#"${lastline%?}"}" != "$newline" ] && echo >> file
# Now file is sane; do our normal processing here...
```

Comment: It’s also perfectly unnecessary, unless you expressly wish to sanitize such files. `read` can process them quite nicely, as shown in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14547230/990363).

Answer (score 1):

If you must use read, try this:

```
awk '{ print $0}' foo | while read line; do
    echo the line is $line
done
```

as awk seems to recognize lines even without the newline char

Comment: I would prefer to stay afar from awk, but it is still a good Idea. Thanks!

Comment: This solution does not require you to do anything advanced with awk.  In fact, if you do a lot with shell scripting, awk is a good tool to have in your back pocket.  It does not take long to learn the basics.  Awk is often useful for file processing.  It can be significantly faster than using shell commands, especially when files are large.

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less a combination of the answers given so far.

It does not modify the files in place.

```
(cat file; tail -c1 file | grep -qx . && echo) | while read line
do
    ...
done
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer, because modifying the file X by rewriting it with a final newline is not always an option to everyone. Further this code is **easy to understand** (which is always a good idea when scripts should not be "write-only") and shortest *and* safest code (see JakeGould's comment). This oneliner could also be stored into a separate script or alias and so is reusable.

Comment: Though I wholeheartedly agree on the rationale, I disagree on the value of the implementation. Besides the fact it uses a perfectly unnecessary amount of externals, looping inside a pipe has [its own share of issues](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14547230/990363) for an internal, current shell only solution.